# How to implement Konno's Mean-Absolute Deviation Portfolio Optimization Model using LP methods in Excel

Tags: portfolio-management, optimization, modern-portfolio-theory, portfolio-optimization, mean-variance

Konno proposed a LP method for portfolio optimization using the Mean Absolute Deviation (MAD)

Comment: What is that supposed to mean you do the question and the answer in quick succession?

Comment: Knowledge sharing since no one else had posed the question

Comment: Do you have anything to do with the spreadsheet? With the original/new paper? Your question is not clear enough by the way, like we would like to have a link to the model you refer to, probably integrate in there the main equation. I'd have closed this straightaway.

Comment: The spreadsheet is mine. Happy to remove the post if you don't feel anyone will find it of any use. I was simply taking the "Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style" at face value. You should be able to download the spreadsheet from the download.xls button after following the link. Alternatively you can use this direct download link https://www.academia.edu/attachments/36780111/download_file?st=MTQyNTk4MDQwOCwyMDIuMTc0LjE3MC4xNjIsMTIyMTAxMg%3D%3D&s=work_strip

Comment: Self promotion ... that's alright, there is a paper and there is a spreadsheet - let me ask you one thing: what is the result - sparse portflios? What is the back-test? I will post a question and you can answer. So far there is some knowledge but a lot of questions open to me.

Comment: http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/16923/what-are-pros-and-cons-of-mean-absolute-deviation-portfolio-optimization

Comment: I'm fine with that I'm just saying your question (not the answer) is a bit "light" and would deserve a bit of embedded background and references. I'd advise you to mention in your answer that you created the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

This [spreadsheet](https://www.academia.edu/11074736/Mean_Absolute_Deviation_MAD_Portfolio_Optimization_in_Excel_and_VBA) shows how to implement Konno's Mean Absolute Deviation (MAD) Portfolio Optimization in Excel using LP Simplex methods.

For strictly multivariate normal underlyings, the method can be shown to be equivalent to the standard Mean Variance Optimization method of Markowitz et al.

The method is based on the paper [Further Reduction of the Konno-Yamazaki Mean-Absolute Deviation Portfolio Optimization Model](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2508777) by Mike Fox.

Comment: I think you should accept your answer.Thanks